# Does rx-java IO Scheduler maintains order?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm wondering if the `Schedulers.io()` will execute tasks in the order of the caller.

```java
public class SaveTest {

    @Inject
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    public void save()  {
        Observable.range(0, 20)
                .map(l -> new MyModel(l))
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(myRepository::save);
    }
}
```

When inserting new data, even if the order is not respected there is no problem. But when updating ex :

```java
    BankAccount account = new BankAccount();
    account.deposit(500);
    account.withdraw(50);
```

and each operation results in a save in a reactive stream the order is very important.

**My question is : Does IO Scheduler maintains order ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes a reactive stream maintains the order of events, even if you hand off the events to a different scheduler like this.

Internally the events are put in a queue, and a single threaded worker selected by the scheduler ([as documented here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#io--)) picks them up from the queue, in order.

Comment: so each time we call `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())` it peeks a thread from the pool and this thread will takes events in the order of there emissions ?

Comment: Basically yes. Technically the thread is picked when you subscribe, not when you call `observeOn`.

Comment: Is this true for the other schedulers ?

Comment: All the built-in schedulers document that they use single threaded workers, but you can create a custom scheduler with multithreaded workers with Schedulers.from - the docs warn you about this:  "Note, however, if the provided ScheduledExecutorService instance is not single threaded, tasks scheduled with a time delay close to each other may end up executing in different order than the original schedule() call was issued."